# Batch file to search list of PCs for a folder/file and create log file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to get a script to seach all the pcs on my network and tell me if a folder is present within the C directory.

Here's the script I've got so far, it is working but it is not pulling through the list of PCS from the file specified.. It is always running on my PC alone.

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f %%a in (c:\pcs.txt) do IF EXIST "C:\HMSJAVA\jt400.jar" (
echo %computername% has HMS GUI locally installed. >> "c:\hmsguipcs.txt"
GOTO :END
) ELSE ( Goto :NoHMS
)


:NoHMS
IF NOT EXIST "C:\HMSJAVA\jt400.jar" (
echo %computername% does NOT have HMS GUI locally installed. >> "c:\hmsguipcs.txt"
GOTO :END
)

:END
PAUSE


*****MY PCs File pcs.txt*****
    COMPUTER1
    COMPUTER2
    COMPUTER3
```

Got it working, what I did was add the for /f command to the if not exist command, and then ran the batch using psexec. I also had to change all teh stuff specific to the C drive to our public shared drive. Works like a charm now!

Comment: show your `pcs.txt` file

Comment: It's just a text file with pc names, PC1 (next line) PC2 (next line) PC3. -Not sure how to make new lines in a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only testing your C: drive for the file.

You need to specify a network path for the If NOT Exists command.

```
IF NOT EXIST "\\%%A\C$\HMSJAVA\jt400.jar"
```

I'd put it in an echo to see if it's right.

The hidden admin share C$ may not be available. Choose another share you made.